# Rails no route error, while the rake routes gives the route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes, nested

I am dealing with a nested resource "farm" in Rails, and my form for making new farm looks like this:

```
 <%= form_for([@user, @farm], :url=> new_user_farm_path(@user)) do |f| %>
 <% if @farm.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@farm.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this farm from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @farm.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :contact %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :contact %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :adress %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :adress %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

My corresponding "new" function in the farms controller is:

```
 def new
  @farm = Farm.new
  @user = User.find(current_user)


   respond_to do |format|
   format.html # new.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @farm }
end
end
```

It renders the form just fine, but after I click submit, and it actually tries to create new Farm, I get this error:

```
 No route matches [POST] "/users/2/farm/new"
```

In my rake routes, I clearly have thie route showing:

```
     user_farm POST   /users/:user_id/farm(.:format) {:action=
    create", :controller=>"farms"}
```

I am only guessing that the problem is in my create function:

```
 def create
@farm = Farm.new(params[:farm])
@user = User.find(current_user)


respond_to do |format|
  if @farm.save
    format.html { redirect_to user_farm(@user, @farm), notice: 'Farm was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @farm, status: :created, location: @farm }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @farm.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

My routes.rb file:

```
  resources :users do
  resource :farm
  end


  devise_for :users, :path => 'accounts'
```

I am accessing my new farm form via this link:

```
 <%= link_to "New Farm", new_user_farm_path(current_user) %>
```

My entire rake routes:

```
           user_farm POST   /users/:user_id/farm(.:format)       {:action=>"
           create", :controller=>"farms"}
           new_user_farm GET    /users/:user_id/farm/new(.:format)   {:action=>"
           new", :controller=>"farms"}
           edit_user_farm GET    /users/:user_id/farm/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"
           edit", :controller=>"farms"}
                     GET    /users/:user_id/farm(.:format)       {:action=>"
           show", :controller=>"farms"}
                     PUT    /users/:user_id/farm(.:format)       {:action=>"
           update", :controller=>"farms"}
                     DELETE /users/:user_id/farm(.:format)       {:action=>"
           destroy", :controller=>"farms"}
               users GET    /users(.:format)                     {:action=>"
           index", :controller=>"users"}
                     POST   /users(.:format)                     {:action=>"
           create", :controller=>"users"}
            new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                 {:action=>"
           new", :controller=>"users"}
           edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"
           edit", :controller=>"users"}
                user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"
           show", :controller=>"users"}
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"
           update", :controller=>"users"}
                     DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"
           destroy", :controller=>"users"}
           new_user_session GET    /accounts/sign_in(.:format)          {:action=>"
           new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_session POST   /accounts/sign_in(.:format)          {:action=>"
           create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           destroy_user_session GET    /accounts/sign_out(.:format)         {:action=>"
           destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /accounts/password(.:format)         {:action=>"
           create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
           new_user_password GET    /accounts/password/new(.:format)     {:action=>"
           new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
           edit_user_password GET    /accounts/password/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"
           edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                     PUT    /accounts/password(.:format)         {:action=>"
           update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
           cancel_user_registration GET    /accounts/cancel(.:format)            {:action=>"
           cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
           user_registration POST   /accounts(.:format)                  {:action=>"
           create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
           new_user_registration GET    /accounts/sign_up(.:format)           {:action=>"
           new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
           edit_user_registration GET    /accounts/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"
           edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                     PUT    /accounts(.:format)                  {:action=>"
           update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                     DELETE /accounts(.:format)                  {:action=>"
           destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
           user_confirmation POST   /accounts/confirmation(.:format)     {:action=>"
           create", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
           new_user_confirmation GET    /accounts/confirmation/new(.:format) {:action=>"
           new", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
                     GET    /accounts/confirmation(.:format)     {:action=>"
           show", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
           user_unlock POST   /accounts/unlock(.:format)           {:action=>"
           create", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
           new_user_unlock GET    /accounts/unlock/new(.:format)       {:action=>"
           new", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
                     GET    /accounts/unlock(.:format)           {:action=>"
           show", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
           home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                {:controlle
           r=>"home", :action=>"index"}
                root        /                                    {:controlle
           r=>"home", :action=>"index"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your form is attempting to make a POST request to a url that only exists for GET requests. So it's telling you that

```
[POST] "/users/2/farm/new"
```

doesn't exist -- which it doesn't. And your `rake routes` output confirms this -- the cloesst thing is

```
new_user_farm GET    /users/:user_id/farm/new(.:format)
```

which is a GET request.

Forms default to using POST for new record creation, so you need to supply a url that can be POSTed to. Or you can let Rails figure it out from the state of your objects. So either

```
<%= form_for([@user, @farm], :url=> user_farm_path(@user)) do |f| %>
```

OR

```
<%= form_for([@user, @farm]) do |f| %>
```

should work. In the former case we're using a named route that matches a POST route from your `rake routes` output. In the latter case we're letting rails figure it out based on the state of your `@farm` object. That is, if `@farm` is a `new_record?` it'll submit a POST request to `/users/:user_id/farm`, or if `@farm` is `persisted?` then it'll submit a PUT request to `/users/:user_id/farm`. (Same path, just different request type.)

Comment: Yeah, that was a problem. Sorry, just another question, since I am a beginner. Why it wont show the farm I just created to me. It says: Couldn't find Farm without an ID. I am strongly suspecting that my create function is somehow not good. Can you please check it, and make sure it is okay?

Comment: `@farm = Farm.new(params[:farm])` looks right... can you put a debugger into your create action and check the result? I'm not sure why it's asking about finding a Farm when you're wanting to create one. Are you in the wrong action perhaps? Also, if you already have `current_user` then you don't need to do the `@user = User.find(current_user)` bit at all -- just use `current_user`.

Comment: I've changed that in my create farm, but i still get the same error. It redirects me to this link:http://localhost:3000/users/2/farm.11. I am guessing my redirect_to in my create function is not okay either.

Comment: Oh, ok. So take note of my edits in my comment above... I was confused for a second. So yeah, the redirect_to in your create action should be `user_farm_path(@user, @farm)` not just `user_farm(@user, @farm)`.

Comment: Furthermore, as @Rich Peck said, it looks like you want `resources :farms` in your routes file, not just `resource :farm`.

Comment: I want resource:farm. I used your redirect_to, but, I still get the same error:ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in FarmsController#show. Couldn't find Farm without an ID. 

As I understand after creation of the farm, it should immediatly go to show it. Only thing left is to show you my show function?

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

--

**Params**

When you create a new ActiveRecord object in Rails, you'll want to use `strong params`:

```
#app/controllers/farms_controller.rb
Class FarmsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @farm = Farm.new
   end

   def create
      @farm = Farm.new(farm_params)
   end

   private

   def farm_params
      params.require(:farm).permit(:params, :for, :farm)
   end
end
```

--

**Routes**

You're using [nested routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), which can be tricky if you're not used to it.

If you haven't already, you should do this with your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :farm #-> /users/3/farm/new
end
```

This will give you the ability to reach that route either from your controller or views.
If you give me some more info (Routes file), I'll be able to help further!

--

**POST**

Having looked over the issue again, it seems I made an oversight before!!!

As pointed out by `pdbobb`, the error certainly says you're trying to reach `/new` with a `POST` verb. This is not correct, as according to the Rails resourceful routing conventions, you need to

[image]

You'll be able to use `pdobb`'s answer, but more importantly, we need to establish *why* your form is trying to submit to the `new` post.

The problem is likely with your `nested` resource

Comment: I've added some more info, please tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: Exactly, form renders without problems. I fill these three fields, click "Create farm", and it gives me that error.

Comment: Hmm - does it reference a particular line or anything?

Comment: Nothing, it only says: Routing Error, and then it gives that error. That is one of the reasons it is so confusing. I really don't know what else to try. Btw, I've added your suggestion for strong params, thank you for that. I really hope we will be able to figure this out.

Comment: I used @pdobb's answer, but now it wont show the farm, as you can see in my comment to his answer.

Comment: Still broken. I am updating situation in the comments to the @pdobb's answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56840/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-admir-huric).